# Criteria Query with many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria

I have two entities: Project and Role with a many to many relationship. I'm trying to select the projects containing a certain role with the Criteria API, but my code isn't working. I use Hibernate and Spring-boot. I don't use Metamodel.

Here are my entities:
Project:

```
@Entity
public class Project
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private List<Role> roles;

    //Constructors getters and setters omitted
}
```

Role:

```
@Entity
public class Role
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    @Column
    private String name;

    //constructors getters and setters omitted
}
```

And here the query:

```
public List<Project> findByRole(Role role)
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<Project> criteria = builder.createQuery(Project.class);
    Root<Project> root = criteria.from(Project.class);

    Path<List<Role>> roles = root.get("roles");
    Expression<Role> roleParameter = builder.parameter(Role.class, "role");

    criteria.select(root).where(roleParameter.in(roles));

    TypedQuery<Project> query = session.createQuery(criteria)
                                        .setParameter("role", role);
    List<Project> projects = query.getResultList();

    return projects;
}
```

This query returns null no matter what kind of data is in the database. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I'm very new to the Criteria API and I can't make sense of it. I'm grateful for any help.

Comment: `where(builder.equal(root.join("roles"), role))`. But seriously, why are you making your own life miserable by using the criteria API for static queries like that? Criteria is useful for dynamic queries. Just use JPQL: `select distinct project from Project project join project.roles role where role = :role`. And fi using the criteria API, why don't you use the metamodel, which at least makes it safer?

Comment: The answer to all of these is: because I don't know what I'm doing. I did some course on how to build a basic spring web app, and I'm now trying to move from that to slightly more advanced stuff by trying to develop my own projects. But I stumble on lots of stuff I don't understand. I tried using Criteria without Metamodel because the instructor did. Thank you for both giving me the answer and helping me find out better ways to do this.

Comment: If you're doing this inside a Spring webapp, then you missed a few stuff. You should never open a session by yourself. You shouldn't even use the Hibernate session API, BTW, but the JPA API. And Spring should be configured with a JPATransactionManager, so that it handles JPA transactions for you.

Comment: I'll look into this, thanks.